# rename a string in a perl script eg name("this stays the same")

Tags: perl

```
perl -pi-back -e 's/ACTUAL_WORD\(`SOMETHING`\)/EXPECTED_WORD\(`SOMETHING`\)/g;' \
inputfile.txt
```

I need the "something" to stay the same. something is like a variable that changes.

Comment: How about `s/ACTUAL_WORD/EXPECTED_WORD/g`? Or are there lines that do not have the `(SOMETHING)` and you want to skip them?

Comment: the something varies from line to line. need to edit both sides of the something its like "ACTUAL_WORD\(`SOMETHING`\)ACTUAL_WORD"

Comment: or hello_something_shop

Comment: Can you give some sample text that you're trying to replace, and what to replace with?

Comment: You should say that in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should do it?

```
perl -pi-back -e 's/ACTUAL_WORD(.*)/EXPECTED_WORD($1)/g;' inputfile.txt
```

You capture the word in brackets and reuse it via `$1` in the replacement. (You may need more brackets - it's unclear if additional are required based on your input).